# preg_match last characters after hyphen

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

Can anybody help me please. I get an url and need to take the last part after `-`.

**Example data**

- `game-when-no-one-at-xhU8c0dL`
- `coins-at-the-desk-1xhz83c`
- `example-example-1391340`

**Result needed**

- `xhU8c0dL`
- `1xhz83c`
- `1391340`

I just made a regex to take some last characters, but number of symbols can be 7 or 8.

```
preg_match('/.{7}(?=($|\r|\n))/')
```

---

**Edit**

This will work: `preg_match('/[^-]*$/')`

Comment: Try `preg_match('~.*-(.*)$~')`

Comment: preg_match('/[^-]*$/')

Comment: You can also use [`preg_match('/-\K[^-]{7,8}$/', $str, $out);`](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxj7AI4CLS6W4pEjBVkE9PTE3Vbc8IzVPNy9fNz8vVTexRLciI9Qi2SDFR92aiyszTaOgKDU9PjexJDlDQ11fN8Y7Ok43ttpcx6JWRV9dRwFkEJDMLy3R1ORSUEhNzsgH86INYq3//wcA) [Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/8tuJQX/1)

Comment: Don't use a regex for that: `$result = ltrim(strrchr($str, '-'), '-');`